# Toggling between two image sources

Tags: javascript, html

I want to toggle between two images one is "edit.png" and another "ok.png", when page loads it should shows "edit.png" and when we click on edit.png it should changes to ok.png. i have tried with the following java script code, but this code is applying only to the first edit.png image in my table it is not applying to next edit.png image. Anyone suggest how can i apply this java script code to every edit.png image in my table. For table i used the "tabledit" plugin.
[screen shot my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA1xO.png)

```js
var toggle = false;
function changing() {
    if (toggle === true) {
        document.getElementById('edit').src  = '/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png';
    } else {
       document.getElementById('edit').src = '/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_ok.png';
 
    }
    toggle = !toggle; 
}
```

```html
<img src="/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png" id="edit" onclick="changing()"/>
```

Comment: Reason it loads only one is because src just loads the image on page load/refresh. After the initial loading, you should use another way of loading the image like AJAX.

Comment: Or you can also load both of them on a hidden div, and toggle (show/hide) them as needed.

Comment: do you realize you can only have one element with an id?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally display both images, and toggle the visibility instead of the url:

```js
var toggle = true;
function changing() {
  document.getElementById('edit').style.display = toggle ? 'none' : 'block';
  document.getElementById('ok').style.display = toggle ? 'block' : 'none';
  toggle = !toggle; 
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" onclick="changing()" id="edit"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" onclick="changing()" id="ok" style="display:none">
```

But if you really want it, you can load the image using Ajax. That will involve a lot more work. I would use the [jquery implementation of ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in that case.

[There is an ajax answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920514/using-ajax-jquery-to-refresh-an-image)

Comment: -here i am adding images through " tabledit" plugin in javascript  file hence again it is applying to first images only. please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to load both images, and toggle the *display=none* style property with Jquery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```js
function changing() {
  $('#edit').toggle();
  $('#ok').toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" id="edit" onclick="changing()"/>
<img style="display:none;" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="ok" onclick="changing()"/>
```

Comment: JQuery isn't part of the original question and unnecessary

Comment: If the OP does not want to use Jquery, then it can use your answer. I'm just giving him possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function is only updating the first image in your table is because `getElementById('edit')` is targeting the first image on the DOM with `id='edit'`.

**IDs are meant to be unique, and so each of your images should have a unique ID.**

One approach would be to make your `changing()` function take in a parameter for `imageId`:

```
var toggle = false;
function changing(imageId) {
    if (toggle === true) {
        document.getElementById(imageId).src  = '/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png';
    } else {
       document.getElementById(imageId).src = '/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_ok.png';

    }
    toggle = !toggle; 
}
```

And pass the `imageId` parameter in from your `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png" id="edit-row-1" onclick="changing('edit-row-1')"/>
```

Remember you'll have to ensure every image tag contains it's own unique ID. So your images on every row would look something along the lines of this:

```
<!-- row 1 -->
<img src="/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png" id="edit-row-1" onclick="changing('edit-row-1')"/>

<!-- row 2 -->
<img src="/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png" id="edit-row-2" onclick="changing('edit-row-2')"/>

<!-- row 3 -->
<img src="/concrete5/application/images/animated/btn_edit.png" id="edit-row-3" onclick="changing('edit-row-3')"/>
```

Comment: no here i am dynamically adding rows so how it works.

Comment: Your IDs in the `<img>` tag could be dynamically defined as well. What method are you using to dynamically add your rows?